# Error 524 A timeout occurred when creating a configurable product with variation images cloudflare

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.4.5, timeout

Error 524 A timeout occurred when creating a configurable product with variation images. (but products are created when I refresh page.)

If there are no images on variations, a timeout error doesn't happen. (Only happens when I create with images) [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means admin took more than 100 seconds for creating configurable product. You have some ways to fix:

- Create a page rule which by pass cloudflare timeout on cloudflare dashboards (Require pro version).
- or import your product via import file
- or update your hosts file which bypass cloudflare cdn (Make sure your IP is whitelisted):
- Cloudflare document https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-5XX-errors#524error